# Logarithm of polynomial behavior in limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I have a sequence $a_n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_n}{\log n} = 0$.

Let $poly(n) := \sum_{i\in S} c(i) n^i > 0$, where $S$ is some finite subset of real numbers and $c(i)$ are real numbers. Does it hold that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_n}{\log  \left(poly(n)\right)} = 0$$

My idea to prove this is to bound the polynomial with the largest and smallest terms. There exists some $r, s\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n^s\geq poly(n) \geq n^r$. Using the monotonicity of the logarithm to obtain

$$ \frac{a_n}{\log \left(n^s\right)} \leq \frac{a_n}{\log \left( poly(n)\right)} \leq \frac{a_n}{\log \left(n^r\right)}$$

By the sandwich rule, the limit in the middle goes to zero since

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{r\log n} = 0, \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{s\log n} = 0$$

Is this proof correct or is there some sequence $a_n$ for which this argument fails?

Comment: Do you intend $S$ to contain only positive real numbers? If so then the argument seems valid. Also there's no reason to call the function $\poly$ (which is misleading) when $f$ suffices.

Comment: No, $S$ can contain negative real numbers too. Why is the argument invalid in this case? Can I not still bound the polynomial function by some $n^r$ where $r$ is negative?. Thanks for the comments on notation!

Comment: If there's a single $i=0$ then the function is constant and the conclusion can fail. If all the $i$s are negative, then the conclusion holds but one needs to be more careful with the inequalities in the intermediate steps.